Error while migration after installation of rest_framework_api_key
I am trying to use this library. But I am getting below error while trying to run python manage.py migrate command.
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, rest_framework_api_key, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying rest_framework_api_key.0001_initial... OK
  Applying rest_framework_api_key.0002_auto_20190529_2243...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/foysal/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 676, in get_field
    return self.fields_map[field_name]
KeyError: 'revoked'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

And
File "/home/foysal/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 678, in get_field
    raise FieldDoesNotExist(
django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: APIKey has no field named 'revoked'


Just double checking, what version of Django do have and which version of Django Rest Framework? Also what are you using for your Database? SQLite or Postgres, something else?
If it's not an issue with this, it's likely the first migration failed, I'd recommend trying again from scratch.
